# Center pictures and description in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I center 2 pictures, one after another? Every picture has a description that stands at the right of the picture.

CSS

```
.message-icon_description {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #606060;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    .left-logo img {
            float: left;
            margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="message-icons">
    <div class="left-logo">
        <img src="./images/blue.png" alt="blue-message-logo">
            <div class="message-icon_description">
                <p>Description1</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="message-icons">
    <div class="left-logo">
        <img src="./images/yellow.png" alt="yellow-message-logo">
        <div class="message-icon_description">
            <p>Description2</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried by now, but it's not working well, it shows me picture1_description1 picture2_description2 as I want, but they are not centred, they begin from the left. Any suggestions?

Comment: The CSS code is floating the `img` tags to the left, which is not center: `float: left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```css
.message-icon_description {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.left-logo {
  display:flex;
}

.left-logo img {
  //float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="message-icons">
    <div class="left-logo">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwy9x2ChZ-mbHy-lx9ZPRe5ZhIk3SLHCMBVzMaiTlg_3bSIOAn6fC3Wjk" alt="blue-message-logo">
      <div class="message-icon_description">
        <p>Description1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message-icons">
    <div class="left-logo">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwy9x2ChZ-mbHy-lx9ZPRe5ZhIk3SLHCMBVzMaiTlg_3bSIOAn6fC3Wjk" alt="yellow-message-logo">
      <div class="message-icon_description">
        <p>Description2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want them one after another.. on the same line I mean

Comment: Add display:flex; to container class in my example.

Comment: @mr.wizz I have updated the above code snippet, check it out and tell me if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as though you're looking to display the images next to each other, centralised, with their descriptions underneath. To achieve this, you're looking to create a **container** for the messages which has `text-align: center`, in addition to making `.message-icons` display as `inline-block`:

```css
.message-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.message-icons {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-container">

  <div class="message-icons">
    <div class="left-logo">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="blue-message-logo">
      <div class="message-icon_description">
        <p>Description1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message-icons">
    <div class="left-logo">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="yellow-message-logo">
      <div class="message-icon_description">
        <p>Description2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, it helped a lot!